# Why did the Roman soldiers compete to possess Jesus' clothes?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, gospel-of-john, crucifixion

John 19: 23-24 reads: "When the soldiers crucified Jesus, they took his clothes, dividing them into four shares, one for each of them, with the undergarment remaining. This garment was seamless, woven in one piece from top to bottom. “Let’s not tear it,” they said to one another. “Let’s decide by lot who will get it.”

Question: What was the purpose of soldiers keeping the blood-soaked clothes of Jesus who had been equated to a criminal  ? Did they keep those clothes in the form of trophies to keep  count of those whom they crucified ? Does the Catholic Church have an official teaching on this incident ?

Comment: Where do you get that the clothes were blood-soaked?

Comment: Please see Mark 15:17 : "And they clothed him in a purple cloak ...." Mk 16: 20: " And  when they had mocked him, they stripped him of the purple cloak, and put his own clothes on him. And they led him out to crucify him ". Clearly, Jesus was clothed as he was carrying the cross after the scourging and thorn-crowning . Please don't say  that Jesus had low HB count .

Comment: Yup... and he wasn't clothed in the clothes they were raffling off. They removed his valuable cloak before he got bloody.

Comment: Downvoting this because none of the scriptures you have quoted so far have provided ANY evidence of the very question you are asking.

Comment: They did it to fulfil scripture!

Comment: It strikes me that removing the two words "blood soaked" would do wonders for this question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I think it would render the question obsolete, since the question is "why did the Romans want to gamble for worthless clothing?" If they weren't blood soaked, then it becomes obviously apparent that the clothes were not worthless.

Comment: Perhaps another question asking how the clothes wouldn't be worthless would be good to ask. Also many commentators think the clothes would include his shoes and belt, so would be easier to clean.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the possessions of an executed criminal was a pretty standard perk for soldiers of the time. It may not seem like much of a perk to us, but clothing was a significant expense at the time (as it is in many parts of the world today). 'Blood-soaked' wouldn't have been a problem. Things can be cleaned, especially if they were valuable. Just because you are a criminal doesn't mean that your clothing is rags.

A 'seamless robe' was actually a pretty nice piece of clothing, and well worth competing for. That also explains why they decided to cast lots rather than tear it into shares.

Answer (score 0):

In Psalm 22:18 it says "For dogs have surrounded Me; the congregation of the wicked has enclosed Me. They divide My garments among them, and for My clothing they cast lots.”

It was a prophecy that was being fulfilled even in the act of Jesus' death. Besides that, the Roman soldiers probably were just making a game out of an everyday situation for them.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the soldiers' motivation.

Comment: Yeah, the soldiers probably saw it as a common duty that they had to perform and it was something that they wanted to make interesting for them. So they played lots to pass the time.